# Plain Wildcard for Apache's ServerAlias

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf, serveralias

Are there any possible problems with using `ServerAlias *` in an Apache configuration?

One thing I considered: [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) is based on HTTP_HOST in HTTP headers delivered by the client, which can obviously be modified manually by the client. Is there any value that the user could send via the HTTP_HOST which could be harmful/damaging to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there shouldn't be need for that. If none of the other `VirtualHosts` match the hostname, the server will use the default virtualhost, which is the first virtualhost in the configuration. Therefore the default virtualhost is usually named `000-default`; just to become first in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

So you can achieve the same outcome by renaming the symlink in `sites-enabled` to be the first. Or you could make the `000-default` to be a redirection to your actual domain.

I don't think there's currently any known vulnerability in Apache that could use just `HTTP_HOST`. However, it depends on the applications you are running on the default virtualhost, e.g. a PHP script that allows to modify some exploitable variable through `HTTP_HOST`. Actually by making the `000-default` just a redirection you could also prevent that (minor) risk.

Answer (score 2):

No, is the short answer, in my understand. As mentioned by [Esa Jokinen](https://serverfault.com/a/684672/194845) Apache itself may not be directly harmed from just using `HTTP_HOST` it can however create problems for an application running on Apache. From there the possibility of malicious attacks grow exponentially.

After reading this article *[Practical HTTP Host header attacks](http://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html)* one can better understand how `HTTP_HOST` attacks can occur, and what they might affect. In the article an attack example uses curl to spoof the `HTTP_HOST` to include extra unintended content. Here's a similar example for connecting to your localhost and saving the output:

```
curl -H "Host: fakehostPLUS\"onerror='alert(1)'rel='stylesheet'" localhost -o file.html
```